# Rotating geometry and shifting angles in clockwise direction in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have point (cp) and line layer (one row each) in my PostgreSQL database. The point (cp) is on line layer and the direction of line is 112 degrees.

[image: scenario]

For cp, following code generates a buffer of 50 meters and divides the buffer (circle) into 12 sections (pie-like wedges):

```
WITH circle AS
    (
    SELECT gid, ST_Buffer(geom, 50,25) as geom FROM cp
    ),
dump AS (
    SELECT gid, (ST_DumpPoints(ST_Buffer(geom,60,3))).geom as geom 
    FROM cp
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT gid, geom FROM cp
    ),
triangles AS    (
    SELECT gid, (ST_Dump(ST_DelaunayTriangles(ST_Collect(geom),0, 0))).geom geom
    FROM dump
    GROUP BY gid
    )
 SELECT a.gid as pt_id, ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom) geom
 FROM circle as a, triangles as b
```

The output of above code (with line and point layer) is:

[image: code output]

I need to rotate circle segments geometry i.e., I need to align 1st segment with line direction (112 degrees) such that starting from this direction, all other segments follow a step of 30 degrees till last segment. For example, 112, 142, 172 and so on. The desired output scenario could be like:

[image: desired scenario]

I am aware that `ST_Rotate()` function rotates the geometry but it does in counterclock wise according to this [link](http://www.postgis.net/docs/ST_Rotate.html) while I need to rotate circle segments according to line direction (clockwise).

Can anyone suggest me how to use ST_Rotate() for clockwise rotation?

Comment: There are examples in http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Rotate.html including --Rotate 60 degrees clockwise from centroid. Are you not satisfied with that? Also, if you turn 90 degrees clockwise you are in the same position as if you turned 270 degrees counterclockwise, don't you agree?

Comment: Well, too bad of me!! Thanks to you for pointing that out and adding this line 'ST_Rotate(geom, - 112 * pi()/180 , ST_Centroid(pt_geom)) geom  from sections' rotated first segment to the line direction (112 degrees). But, I am still missing the desired output somehow.